# Different result pandas Groupby in Python for DF based on Excel and CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, pandas-groupby

To make my code faster, I want to switch from Excel input to CSV input data. First, I create two df's that are exactly the same.

```
demand_data = pd.ExcelFile("Input Data\Historical Demand.xlsx")
FY20 = pd.read_excel(demand_data, 'Data FY20')
FY20b = pd.read_csv("Input Data\Historical Demand FY20.csv")
```

The resulting df's are:
[Based on Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wirIL.png) [Based on CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5loCK.png)

Next, I want to group my df by some columns using pandas groupby and sum over some colums. I use the following code:

```
FY20 = FY20.groupby(['SKU', 'Material', 'Plant'])[["OrderQuantity","DeliveredQuantity"]].sum().reset_index()
FY20b = FY20b.groupby(['SKU', 'Material', 'Plant'])[["OrderQuantity","DeliveredQuantity"]].sum().reset_index()
```

This is the result:
[Result based on Excel DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmwjo.png) [Result based on CSV DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7p4Q.png)

This does not make any sense to me, since the two dataframes are exactly the same, but the result is not. How do I get the same groupby result from the CSV based dataframe?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably because your numbers in the CSV are strings (e.g. `1,516.0`), you can notice that from the commas. You'll need to remove those and then convert the resulting strings to integer columns:

```py
FY20b["OrderQuantity"] = FY20b["OrderQuantity"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',', ''))
FY20b["OrderQuantity"] = pd.to_numeric(FY20b["OrderQuantity"])

FY20b["DeliveredQuantity"] = FY20b["DeliveredQuantity"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',', ''))
FY20b["DeliveredQuantity"] = pd.to_numeric(FY20b["DeliveredQuantity"])
```

Then you can do:

```py
FY20b = FY20b.groupby(['SKU', 'Material', 'Plant'])[["OrderQuantity","DeliveredQuantity"]].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thanks!